# How can I integrate/embed MVC app into the Sitecore desktop?

Tags: sitecore-client, mvc

I've got a third party MVC app that I would like to integrate into the Sitecore 7.2 desktop so that users logging into Sitecore can use it. I've seen the answers for using [compiled DLLs as renderings](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6405/i-need-to-integrate-a-controller-from-a-compiled-dll-into-a-controller-i-can-bui) and [adding apps to the desktop using Sitecore 8 and Webforms](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/how-can-i-create-an-app-and-insert-it-in-the-desktop) but neither is the right fit. I've gone into the Core DB and added a new application, linking it to the app's controller with the `/api/sitecore/{controller}/{action}` url format, but all I get out is an error that

> The controller can either not be found or it doesn't implement
>   IController

When run by itself the web app works just fine. I've removed the elements that would conflict with my Sitecore app's web frontend, like `App_Start` and `Global.asax`. Any ideas?

Note: I'm not asking, how to code Sitecore using MVC, I just have a different project in the solution that I'd like to run in a window in the client.

Answer (score 1):

Application in Sitecore backend works in a same way as Sitecore pages.

You need to:

- Create Layout(under /sitecore/layout/Layouts) in core database (as path for layout you can put address of you app. Make sure that you are able to access that path in browser.)
- Create Application item(under /sitecore/content/Applications) in core database and set layout on this item from previous step
- Create shortcut for your app to display it either in Sitecore menu(under /sitecore/content/Documents and settings) or in LaunchPad (under /sitecore/Client/Applications/LaunchPad)